# Build step after gated checkin successful

Tags: azure-pipelines

at the moment we are migrating our XAML-Builds to new TFS Build-System. We have our TFS on premise.

Problem is about gated checkin: After the gated checkin is successful, we create a code review workitem. This is not a problem in XAML Builds. We had written an activity. This activity is executed after the real check-in.

The question is: Is there a way to create a build step (in the new Build-System (vnext)) after the gated checkin is successful? We need the Changeset-Id the build created.

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, you could associate work item when you check in changes, then the changeset will be associated to corresponding work item after verifying build.

Secondly, you can associate changeset to a work item by using [update work item REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#add-a-link):

For example:

```
PATCH https://[account].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/[work item id]?api-version=1.0
```

ContentType: `application/json-patch+json`

Body:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "ArtifactLink",
      "url": "vstfs:///VersionControl/Changeset/[changeset ID]",
      "attributes": {
        "comment": "apitest",
         "name": "Fixed in Changeset"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

You can use Build.SourceVersion to get ChangeSet. [Build variables](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables)

Simple sample to get chageset through PowerShell task:

Arguments: -v $(Build.SourceVersion)

Scripts:

```
param(
[string]$v
)
Write-Host $v
```

A blog about calling REST API during build: [Calling VSTS APIs with PowerShell](http://blog.devmatter.com/calling-vsts-apis-with-powershell/)